Find a solution of a conservation law
How can I prove that the (entropy) admissible solution of the equation
\begin{equation}
u_t + |u|_x = 0
\end{equation}
is given by
\begin{equation}
u(t,x) = 
\begin{cases}
-1,\quad\text{if}\quad x<-t
\\
\phantom{-}0, \quad\text{if}\quad -t<x<t  \quad ?
\\ 
\phantom{-}1, \quad\text{if}\quad x>t
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The solution satisfies the Rankine-Hugoniot Conditions, so it is a distributional solution, but I don't know how to prove that it is an admissible solution.
An (entropy) admissible solution $u$ must satisfy
\begin{equation} \int_0^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} |u-k| \phi_t + sgn(u-k) \left(|u| - |k|\right) \phi_x dx dt\ge 0\end{equation} for all $\phi$ test function with compact support and for all real $k$. But I think there is another way to prove that

It would probably be helpful to include the definition of being an (entropy) admissible solution.

An (entropy) admissible solution $u$ must satisfy \begin{equation} \int_0^T \int_\mathbb{R} |u-k| \phi_t + sgn(u-k) \left(|u| - |k|\right) \phi_x dx dt\ge 0\end{equation} for all $\phi$ test function with compact support and for all real $k$. But I think there is another way to prove that

The solution for $u_t+\left(\sqrt{u^2}\right)_x = 0$ is $u(x,t) = \phi\left(x-t \frac{u(x,t)}{\sqrt{u^2(x,t)}}\right)$.

What is $\phi$?
